# Where is DLL entry point in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, embed, .net-assembly

I'm currently trying to embed a DLL (as a resource) in another dll, but I'm having a slight little problem.

**Where is DLL entry point located?** I mean, in a WPF I would have an *app.xaml.cs* file, but what if my project is a library itself?

Where should I, let's say, program `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` so it picks it from resources instead? I don't have a program class to do that.

Answer (score 2):

DLLs don't have entry points.
Instead, classes are loaded and used as necessary.

Instead of handling `AssemblyResolve`, you should simply call `Assembly.Load` in static initializers before using any type from the other assembly.

Comment: Basically I would need to create a static initializer to each class that might have the problem, is that correct? Regarding AssemblyResolve, could I handle it on the projects that are going to use the dll(which contains another dll inside)? That way I'd know exactly where program starts, etc

Comment: @Apidcloud: Yes.  They could all call a common loader method.  Yes; that would also work.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it raised this while trying to use one of the dll classes: The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception; Does this mean that the static constructor is raising the exception?

Comment: Yes. What's the InnerException?

Comment: Seems that it was a problem on the way I embeded the dll...but now it's raising the previous exception: Could not load file or assembly..
Can you take a look on the static constructor? 
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TestProject.testdll.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }

Comment: @Apidcloud: What's the stack trace? Are you sure your static ctor is running first?

Comment: Since that code is inside a static Constructor, it should be called in the first place; Am I wrong?

Comment: @Apidcloud: It depends which class, and whether that class uses types from the DLL in static fields.

Comment: I'm not using any static fields, so I'm almost sure it's called in the first place. I tested the same code without being in the library, and the static constructor was being called right away